# <= vs == in for loop in JS

Tags: javascript

I am beginner at JS and would like to ask question on the difference between <= and == in for loop. If you look at the code below:

```
 let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];

  for(let i =0; i<array.length;i++){
console.log(array[i]);
  }
```

The above code works ok since array is a 0 based. But I wonder why the below codes do not work which are:

```
 let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];

  for(let i =0; i<=array.length;i++){
console.log(array[i]);
  }
```

AND

```
 let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];

  for(let i =0; i==array.length;i++){
console.log(array[i]);
  }
```

Comment: it's all self explanatory. just read operators.

Comment: You should read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement

Comment: What do you think - in your own words - what each loop does?

Comment: @JonasWilms, what I think is that if I use == then since array.length is 3, the code will not work but what if I change length to 2 like let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];
array.length=2;
  for(let i =0; i==array.length;i++){
console.log(array[i]);
  }

Comment: @JonasWilms, if I use <= then I assume <= is like ==.

Comment: 0 is still not 2 (i == array.length ... 0 == 2 ... false). Also <= is obviously not the same as ==.

Comment: @JonasWilms, ok concerning <=. Does it work like this in the first loop it checks if 0 < or = so, should it satisfy one of the requirements to be true, that is, 0 should be either less than or = to 3? RIght?

Comment: Right ...     ... ....

Comment: @JonasWilms, last question,  why <= is not working since in the first loop it is checked if 0 is less than or equal to array.length which is 3 and since 0 is less than 3 it is true???

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working?"

Comment: @JonasWilms, Jonas, ok ok I got it all is perfect there was just typo in my code. Gosh so hard to be beginner:D

Comment: No, it is not at all perfect. If you use <=, the for loop iterates over the arrays indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, yet your array only has 3 entries (0, 1, 2). Therefore, your log will contain one `undefined`. If it would be easy, we would all be experts ...

Comment: @JonasWilms, :D admit Jonas, I just forgot to mention that))) but thank you for your kind explanation. By the way, I wanna express my gratitude for kindly helping and showing the right way.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

As you pointed out, == and <= won't work here because the index is 0 based. Your for loop will continue to execute as long as the second parameter evaluates to true. Since the length of the array with be 1 bigger than the index of last item in the array, == and <= will evaluate to true but there is no item to access beyond the last item of the array.

== and <= would work if you changed your index to start at 1 and then within your loop access elements at index-1.

Answer (score -1):

these are comparison operators .. just remember the second argument  in for loop in condition it will execute when it turn to be true ..

for example:

```
    let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];

    for(let i =0; i==array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i]);
   }
```

Here i ==array.length is not true because array length is 3

Comment: I tried to change length to 2 but still the code is not working:let array =["BMW", 'Honda', 'Mercedes'];
array.length=2;
  for(let i =0; i==array.length;i++){
console.log(array[i]);
  }

Comment: please I really need your help why even if I change length to 2, the code is not working?